# String is not a function

Tags: javascript

I keep on getting a "String is not a function" Error on line five.

```
    function SwapCase(str) { 
    var words = []
    var q = str   
      for (var i = 0; i<q.length; i++) {
          if (q(i) === q(i).toLowerCase) {
           var upper = q(i).toUpperCase
              words.push(upper)
         };
         else {
             var lower = q(i).toLowerCase
                 words.push(lower)
         };
       };
     words.join
       return words;

    };
    SwapCase("HeleEer")
```

I am still a noobie at coding sorry for missing semi-colons and other spacing and indenting errors.

Comment: did you tryto use q.charAt(i) instead of q(i) < which is incorrect

Answer (score 7):

```
q(i)
```

That's a function call, but `q` is a string, not a function.

You can get a single character from a string using array indexing: `q[i]`.

---

Separately, you probably want to call the `toLowerCase` and `toUpperCase` functions.
Also, `words.join` has no effect, for two reasons.

Answer (score 4):

`q(i)` invokes function `q` with parameter `i`.

`q[i]` gets the `i`-th character of string `q`.

There are other things that are wrong in this piece of code, but `q(i)` is the reason for the error you report (namely, *not* invoking the functions `toLowerCase`, `toUpperCase`, `join`).

And while JavaScript does not make you write semicolons, it is a good idea to do so nonetheless, as you can be bitten by some weird errors when you don't expect it.

EDIT: Oh - speaking of semicolons, you must not write one before `else`. In fact, you should not write them after a closing brace at all. You write them after statements, and *not* after blocks, pretty much opposite of what is in the original post.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you need to use `string.toLowerCase()` and `string.toUpperCase()`. Note the parentheses.

Secondly, whatever object you're applying these methods to has to be a string - such as `q` (or `q[i]` if that's what you need, as SLaks suggested). `q(i)` calls function `q()` (which doesn't exist) on `i`.

Answer (score 0):

you could just do it in one line

```
function SwapCase(str) {
for (x = ""; x.length < str.length; x += String.fromCharCode((str.charCodeAt(x.length) - 65 + 32) % 64 + 65));
return x;
}
```

Im using ascii code with a little bit of math to convert it without using if statements

Comment: This will fail for non-alphabetic characters.